# how to move some value in columns start with a word to the next cell beside it in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Not sure if Im able to explain it very well. There are 2 column in my excel sheet. I want to move all value that start with "family" to the cell next to it. Here's some illustration of it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSniX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(LEFT (A:A,6)="Family",A:A,"")`

Or if using Office365: `=IF(LEFT (@A:A,6)="Family",@A:A,"")`

Comment: it return an error value which is #SPILL!

Comment: Ok, in Office365vI think it's `=IF(LEFT (@A:A,6)="Family",@A:A,"")`

Comment: awesom! got it, the function working! Appreciate it